# Centering divs in HTML and CSS but cut-off on mobile screens

Tags: iphone, css, html, center

I have been having some real issues with CSS!

I have the following set up to centre the #Box div, which works perfectly on everything but mobile browsers. Because the screen size of the mobile browser is so narrow the left hand side keeps getting cut-off. I asked something similar previously and have tried to no avail to adjust it.

I have put the container and layout divs in since last time, but still the same problem occurs. Is there any way that I can adjust the code so that the left hand side doesn't keep getting chopped off?

```
    .pageContainer {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-left: 1.82%;
        padding-right: 1.82%;
        position:relative; }

    #LayoutDiv1 {
        clear: both;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        text-align:center;
        position: relative; }

    #Box {
        width: 487px;
        height: 181px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 236px; 
        margin-left: -244px;
        z-index:6; }
```

The html:

```
    <body>
<div class="pageContainer">
    <div id="LayoutDiv1">
    <div id="Twitter">
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/wekaptureit" target="new"><img     src="images/TwitterNORMAL.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/TwitterHOVER.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/TwitterNORMAL.png'"/></a>
    </div>

<div id="Facebook">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/wekaptureit" target="new"><img src="images/fbNORMAL.png" onMouseOver="this.src='images/fbHOVER.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/fbNORMAL.png'"/></a>
</div>

<div>
<img id="Box" src="images/BOX.png" width="487" height="181">
</div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML as well? Possibly in a www.jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: a professional way to handle them is media queries...

Comment: Here the layout of your `.pageContainer` is coming out of screen because of `padding` to it. This maybe causing the problem. Try to give `width:96.36%` instead of 100%. which will make your layout fit to the screen. or else remove `padding`.

Comment: try `box-sizing : border-box` to check if padding is not the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

The smarter way in 2012 to do this is to use [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), [some inspiration here](http://mediaqueri.es/)

You basically create another style sheet which is loaded only for smaller screens. It might seem like an overkill now, but as your website grows, you will thank me for suggesting this (or you cannot ;))

Also, don't do `margin-left: -244px;`, its hacky and can cause cross browser issues. Show us some HTML and we shall show you a cleaner way.

Comment: Hi rizwaniqbal, thank you for the response. I have included the basic html of the page. A cleaner way would be very much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you including a viewport meta tag? It should eliminate any scaling issues you may be having in mobile.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

To you CSS: `<div>`s are block elements, and their default behavior is to expand the width of their parent (100%). Those CSS declarations aren't necessary.

From your code, and layout, it doesn't look like you need `#LayoutDiv1` or to use positioning.

This simpler code takes care of the left-side-cutoff ([here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzmEx/)):

```
.pageContainer {
    margin:0 auto;
}

#LayoutDiv1 {
        margin: auto;
        text-align:center;
}

#Box {
    width: 487px;
    height: 181px;
    top: 236px; 
    margin:236px auto 0;
}
```

And like a prev poster mentioned, you could add a @media query to load a smaller image for #Box on mobile (you can simply add a line or two [or 200] to your existing CSS file):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #Box { background:url('imgs/mobile-hero.jpg'); }
}
```